# Select sub-query using EXEC() to use different database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It doesn't seem to work when trying to use `EXEC()` in the SELECT query.   Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

The remark comment below "--This work" showed the CASE statement work.  But not the "-This doesn't work" part because `EXEC()` isn't compatible

```
SELECT 
   tu.[DisplayCode],
   tt.[TenantName],
   tt.[EntityType],
   tt.[DatabaseName],
   tu.[TenantId],
   tu.[EmployeeId],
   tu.[UserId],
   au.[IsAbcoaAdmin],
   -- This doesn't work.
   CAST(CASE WHEN tu.[EmployeeId] = EXEC('SELECT TOP 1 [EmployeeId] FROM ['+tt.DatabaseName+'].dbo.Employee t1 WHERE t1.[AutoNum] = '+tu.[EmployeeId]+'''') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS IsEmployeeExists
   -- This work.
   --CAST(CASE WHEN tu.[EmployeeId] = (SELECT TOP 1 [EmployeeId] FROM [RodeoNet].dbo.Employee t1 WHERE t1.[AutoNum] = tu.[EmployeeId]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS IsEmployeeExists
FROM [DealPackWebIdentity].[dbo].[ApplicationUser] au
  INNER JOIN [DealPackWebIdentity].[dbo].[TenantUser] tu ON au.[Id] = tu.[UserId]
  INNER JOIN [DealPackWebIdentity].[dbo].[Tenant] tt ON tu.[TenantId] = tt.[TenantId]
WHERE au.[UserName] = @UserName 
AND CAST(CASE WHEN DB_ID(tt.[DatabaseName]) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) = 1 
AND [IsDisable] = 0 
AND tt.[IsActive] = 1
ORDER BY [TenantName], [EntityType]
```

Comment: No, you can't do that; if you need to determin the database at *runtime* you'll need to build and execute the entire statement *dynamically*. When SQL Server compiles a query, it parses and produces an execution plan; this is pre-baked, it can't change based on the *data* at runtime; the fact you need to do this hints at an underlying data model design flaw.

Comment: Note as well that if you *are* using dynamic SQL you should be **parametrising** your parameters, not injecting them, and quoting your dynamic objects properly with `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: It looks like you have a multi-tenant model, you could probably join to a *view* that unions the data from multiple databases. also consider `case when exists(...)`